# Exchange JSON for SAML token

Tags: json, security, soap, oauth, saml

We have a SAML SSO system and SOAP services that consume and check these SAML tokens. Now we want to build a JSON REST proxy on top of these SOAP services with WSO2 ESB.

However to authenticate to a JSON service we can only send a json token. So when the ESB converts the JSON to SOAP, it should convert(propably with the help of an idp) the JSON token to a SAML token so the existing services can handle it.

Is this possible? I can only find the opposite so exchange a SAML token for an OAUTH JSON token.

Comment: See best choices at https://security.stackexchange.com/a/128613/140435

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 doesn't currently have a way to convert a JSON token (JWT) to a SAML Token out of the box. You will have to do custom implementations to achieve this. There are two options as I can see :

1. Create a custom policy to the WSO2 IS STS, secure it UT, send the username (which is read from the subject of JWT) and password (send the base64endoced JWT itself as the password) to STS. Create a custom password callback handler to validate the JWT as the password and issue the SAML Token.
2. Instead of sending a JWT, send an OAuth token, at the ESB, send this token to the OAuth2TokenValidationService of WSO2 Identity Server. OOTB, WSO2 IS sends a JWT in the validation response, but you can write a custom extension to return a SAML Token instead a JWT. You will have to implement the TokenGeneratorImplClass and configure it in the identity.xml under AuthorizationContextTokenGeneration config.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/a/128613/140435